# How to remove \n or \t code in solr

Tags: solr

I'm using solr 6.6.0. (and The core was created with "sample")
When I importing rich document (here HTML) using ExtractingRequestHandler, unnecessary line feed code(\n) and tab characters(\t) are indexed.
I tried setting MappingCharFilterFactory etc, but it was ineffective.
I also referred to the following URL, but there was no effect.

How do you prevent tabs and newline codes (\ n, \ r \ n, \ t) from being indexed?

[Steps I took]

1. access to "http://localhost:8983/solr/#/sample/documents"
2. select my core (sample). And click "document" link in left menu.
3. fill the forms

   - Request-Handler "/update/extract"
   - Document Type File Upload
   - Documetn (s) test.html
   - Extracting Req. Handler Params * unspecified
   - Commit Within 1000
   - Overwrite true
4. Select "text.html" above and execute it.

[Response]

```
Status: success
Response:
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 618
  }
}
```

[QueryResults]

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "indent":"on",
      "wt":"json",
      "_":"1498437444505"}},
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "size_d":20.0,
        "content_type_s":"text/html",
        "filename_txt_ja":"test.html",
        "content_txt_ja":" \n \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n \n AAA\n\tBBB\n\tCCC\nDDD  ",
        "id":"5a311ac9-77fe-46a6-8524-4ab40c8ece4a",
        "_version_":1571244755499614208}]
  }
}
```

I want to disapper these "\n" and "\t" in content_txt_ja field.

and Here is my config xml files

[solrconfig.xml]

```
<requestHandler name="/update/extract" 
                  startup="lazy"
                  class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="lowernames">true</str>
      <str name="uprefix">ignored_</str>

      <!-- capture link hrefs but ignore div attributes -->
      <str name="captureAttr">true</str>
      <str name="fmap.meta">ignored_</str>
      <str name="fmap.a">ignored_</str>
      <str name="fmap.div">ignored_</str>
      <str name="fmap.a">ignored_</str>

      <str name="fmap.stream_content_type">content_type_s</str>
      <str name="fmap.content">content_txt_ja</str>
      <str name="fmap.body">content_txt2_ja</str>
      <str name="fmap.stream_name">filename_txt_ja</str>

      <str name="fmap.author">author_txt_ja</str>
      <str name="fmap.last_author">last_author_txt_ja</str>

      <str name="fmap.creation_date">creation_dt</str>
      <str name="fmap.last_modified">modified_dt</str>
      <str name="fmap.stream_size">size_d</str>

    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

[managed-schema.xml]

```
<dynamicField name="*_txt_ja" type="text_ja"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    <fieldType name="text_ja" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="false">
      <analyzer>
        <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping.txt"/>

        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="(\\n)" replacement=""/>
        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="\n" replacement=""/>
        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="[\\n]" replacement=""/>
        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="[\n]" replacement=""/>
        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="\t" replacement=""/>
        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="\\t" replacement=""/>

        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="\\u000a" replacement=" AAA " />

        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="\u000A" replacement="," />
        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="\u000D" replacement=";" />
        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="\u000D\u000A" replacement="." />


        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="\\u000A" replacement="," />
        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="\\u000D" replacement=";" />
        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="\\u000D\\u000A" replacement="." />

        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="(\\u000A)" replacement="," />
        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="(\\u000D)" replacement=";" />
        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="(\\u000D\\u000A)" replacement="." />


        <!--<tokenizer class="solr.JapaneseTokenizerFactory" mode="search"/>-->　
        <!--<tokenizer class="solr.JapaneseTokenizerFactory" mode="normal"/>-->
        <tokenizer class="solr.JapaneseTokenizerFactory" mode="search" userDictionary="lang/userdict_ja.txt"/>

        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />

        <!-- Reduces inflected verbs and adjectives to their base/dictionary forms (辞書形) -->
        <filter class="solr.JapaneseBaseFormFilterFactory"/>
        <!-- Removes tokens with certain part-of-speech tags -->
        <filter class="solr.JapanesePartOfSpeechStopFilterFactory" tags="lang/stoptags_ja.txt" />
        <!-- Normalizes full-width romaji to half-width and half-width kana to full-width (Unicode NFKC subset) -->
        <filter class="solr.CJKWidthFilterFactory"/>
        <!-- Removes common tokens typically not useful for search, but have a negative effect on ranking -->
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_ja.txt" />
        <!-- Normalizes common katakana spelling variations by removing any last long sound character (U+30FC) -->
        <filter class="solr.JapaneseKatakanaStemFilterFactory" minimumLength="4"/>
        <!-- Lower-cases romaji characters -->
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Comment: I solved this by adding "RegexReplaceProcessorFactory" config to "updateRequestProcessorChain" in solrconfig.xml.

Thankyou @Alessandro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indexing and storing are two different things.
To make it simple :
 - indexed content is used to perform search
 - stored content is used to be returned in the search results

You may remove those special characters from your indexed content playing with the analysis chain as you have done ( I have not tested them but they may be ok).
But removing those special characters from the stored content ( the content that is returned in the response) is a different thing.
You need to clean that content before it reaches Solr OR use some custom Solr plugin to do it at update request processor time.

In case you just don't want that to reach your API response, you could clean just the solr response in your intermediate API layer and return the clean content to the client.

Comment: Thank you very easy to understand commentary.
This answer saved me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alessandro Benedetti and k.se1. As Suggested by k.se1, adding "RegexReplaceProcessorFactory" config to "updateRequestProcessorChain" in solrconfig.xml filter out the /n, /t or any replacements you want.

```
<requestHandler name="/update/extract"
                  startup="lazy"
                  class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="update.chain">extract</str>
      <str name="lowernames">true</str>
      <str name="fmap.meta">ignored_</str>
      <str name="fmap.content">_text_</str>
      <str name="capture">h1</str>
      <str name="fmap.h1">h1_content</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>

<updateRequestProcessorChain name="extract">
    <processor class="solr.RegexReplaceProcessorFactory"> 
        <str name="fieldName">h1_content</str> 
        <str name="pattern">\n</str> 
        <str name="replacement"></str> 
    </processor> 
    <processor class="solr.RegexReplaceProcessorFactory"> 
        <str name="fieldName">h1_content</str> 
        <str name="pattern">\t</str> 
        <str name="replacement"></str> 
    </processor> 
    <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
 </updateRequestProcessorChain>
```